# Content subscription model through IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app-subscription, patreon

We're developing an app similar to patreon.

The app will allow creators to publish their content on the platform and users to see that content. The content will be available only through the app. Users also can subscribe to the creators and get access to some premium content.

So my question is how can I set up this type of payments through the IAP or how can I justify direct link to outside payment form like Patreon.

Standard recurrent IAP's are not suitable here. The user can have different amount of subscriptions of different prices, so every month the sum will be different or it will be several different payments.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? This is notoriously difficult to find out

Comment: @FareeshVijayarangam unfortunately no. But instagram is now experimenting with this. I think they use just a lot of subscription groups for different users. we tried this approach but it didn't work well in our case. It is hard to deal with accounting and stuff. so in the end we dropped paid subscriptions. Im still confused how pattern managed to use external links directly from their app

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides a list of apps that may use purchase methods other than in-app purchase, see paragraph [3.1.3 Other Purchase Methods](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#other-purchase-methods) in the App Store Review Guidelines.

Based on the provided information, your app could fall under **3.1.3(d) Person-to-Person Services** or **3.1.3(e) Goods and Services Outside of the App**, which would you allow using other payment methods.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I think 3.1.3(d) is not applicable here, because premium content under subscription will be available to many users, so it is one-to-many service. 3.1.3(e) is may be true, if you can access this content outside the app, which is possible (but not yet). And even if one of these true - I still can't direct users to the subscription page according to 3.1.3 general rule. Which is crucial in my case. (Which Patreon somehow does)